# to fetch multiple numerical value from the list

Tags: matlab

Please help me to find out how to fetch multiple numerical value from the list or to create a list so that I can fetch multiple numerical values.

for ex.-

locations=['50,50,100,100';'50,200,100,300']

I want to draw a rectangle at location [50,50,100,100] i.e. in left upper corner of screen, but I am not able to fetch these dimensions from the location list in my program that i have created for two locations. Please help me.

Comment: The example data is not possible because of an dimension mismatch, please update.

Answer (score 0):

Putting single quotes around a number makes it a string- ie text

'50' (a text value to MATLAB) is not the same as 50 (a double ie number to MATLAB).

What you want is `location = [50 50 100 100];` in the format [x y width height]

If you want to be able to reference an array of locations, you can either store it in a matrix such as this:

```
locations = [ x1 y1 w1 h1 ; 
              x2 y2 w2 h2 ]
```

To reference the nth row, you would use the colon operator to reference the entire dimension, such as `locations(n,:)`

Alternatively, you could use a cell array:

locations{1} = [ x1 y1 w1 h1 ];
locations{2} = [ x2 y2 w2 h2 ];

To reference your nth location, you would do `locations{n}`

[MATLAB rectangle reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) (MATLAB's help is actually quite useful)